# Airflow Hash "#" in day-of-week field not running appropriately

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Hi we are having trouble scheduling task with a #  config as the standard says, to configure for the first, second, third, fourth or fifth day of the week for a given month.

> Hash (#)
> '#' is allowed for the day-of-week field, and must be followed by a number between one and five. It allows specifying constructs such as "the second Friday" of a given month.[19] For example, entering "5#3" in the day-of-week field corresponds to the third Friday of every month.

As is mention here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
Here is my dag config... as you can se, this should run today, the second monday of every month, and it did't run. As this, I have for every day of the month and only on few occasion the task has run successfully. What I'm doing wrong?

> with DAG(dag_id='dag_126_73618_3012xx1the2', default_args=args , concurrency=3, catchup=True, tags=['account_126', 'form'], schedule_interval='30 12 * * 1#2', start_date=datetime(2021 ,8, 1, 0, 0)) as dag:

Here is my complete config

> from airflow import DAG from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago,
> datetime, timedelta from lkf_operator import LKFLogin,
> CreateAndAssignTask
>
> args = {    'owner' : 'airflow',    'email' : ['xxx@linkaform.com',
> 'xxx@linkaform.com'],    'email_on_failure' : True,    'retries' : 3,
> 'retry_delay' : timedelta(seconds=30), }
>
> params = {    'username' : 'xxx@linkaform.com',    'api_key' :
> 'xxxxxx', }
>
> with DAG(dag_id='dag_126_73618_3012xx1the2', default_args=args ,
> concurrency=3, catchup=True, tags=['account_126', 'form'],
> schedule_interval='30 12 * * 1#2', start_date=datetime(2021 ,8, 1, 0,
> 0)) as dag:
>
> ```
> do_run_lkf_login_73618_1 = LKFLogin(
>     name ='LKF Login',
>     task_id ='run_lkf_login_73618_1', 
>     params = params 
> )
>
> do_run_segundo_lunes_del_mes_73618_2 = CreateAndAssignTask(
>     name ='Segundo Lunes del Mes',
>     task_id ='run_segundo_lunes_del_mes_73618_2', 
>     params = {'form_id': 73618, 'assinge_user_id': 126, 'answers': {'61148df86f960aaaa3e4e445': 71925, '611492cc5a6316b13ee4e3f2':
> ```
>
> 'Segundo Lunes del Mes', '61148df86f960aaaa3e4e446': '{% $today %}',
> '61148df86f960aaaa3e4e447': 'pendiente'}}
>
> ```
> )
> ```
>
> do_run_lkf_login_73618_1.set_downstream([do_run_segundo_lunes_del_mes_73618_2])

What is stranger is that for some days it works and from other it dosen't and is the same code, except one or two strings

[image: dags]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid Airflow does not implement the complete crontab with all the flavours. You can check https://crontab.guru/ - this nicely summarizes the crontab specification that is implemented by Airflow.

However, very soon in Airflow 2.2 this problem will be largely solved. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval  - in ~ month when Airflow 2.2 is out, you will be able to use much more flexible and easier to define schedule.

Comment: Grate thanks for you comment. What was strange was that some of the intervals were executed and some not. I checkout python croniter (airflow's crons library ) and it handle very nice this scenarios.